# Spring Integration Wiretap with Annotations (4.3 Spring Integration)

Tags: spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration (4.3) application and i have a JMS receiver which sends the received message to a ServiceActivator.

I am trying to Wiretap a channel, and send the JMS message to Logger (which in this case is Service Activator as well)

I get a strange behavior with the code below.

Every odd message sent (first, third) - it only goes to the logger.

Every even message sent (second, fourth, etc) - only goes to the ServiceActivator that is supposed to do some work and in the future sent the message downstream.

Here are logs

2018-07-23 16:14:43.278  INFO 16532 --- [    container-1] zzz                                      : MSG1

Received via barChannel: MSG2

How can i change my code so all messages go both to the logger and the ServiceActivator that is supposed to do the work?

Thanks a lot in advance

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
    return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
}


@Bean
public JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint inbound() {
    JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint jmsMessageDrivenEndpoint = new JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint(container(), listener());
    jmsMessageDrivenEndpoint.setSessionAcknowledgeMode("transacted");
    jmsMessageDrivenEndpoint.setAutoStartup(true);
    return jmsMessageDrivenEndpoint;
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer container() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
    container.setDestinationName("foo.bar");
    return container;
}

@Bean
public ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener listener() {
    ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener listener = new ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener();
    listener.setRequestChannelName("myLogChannel");
    return listener;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myLogChannel")
public void bar(String in) {
    System.out.println("Received via barChannel: " + in);
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel TappingChannel(MessageChannel myLogChannel) {
    DirectChannel d = new DirectChannel();
    d.addInterceptor(new WireTap("myLogChannel"));
    return d;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myLogChannel")
public MessageHandler logger() {
    LoggingHandler loggingHandler = new LoggingHandler(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO.name());
    loggingHandler.setLoggerName("zzz");
    return loggingHandler;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel myLogChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

EDIT: Here is the original code that works

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel toRouter() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
    return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
}


@Bean
public JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint inbound(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
    return new JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint(container(jmsConnectionFactory), listener());
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
    container.setDestinationName("foo.bar");
    return container;
}

@Bean
public ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener listener() {
    ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener listener = new ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener();
    listener.setRequestChannelName("toRouter");
    return listener;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toRouter")
public void bar(String in) {
    System.out.println("Received via barChannel: " + in);
}
```

I want to do the Wiretap logging on this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mess in your config.

First of all you have two `@ServiceActivator` for the same `myLogChannel` `DirectChannel`.
By default it uses a round-robin dispatching strategy. That's why you see that odd/even behavior between your two consumers on the same channel.

You separate `TappingChannel` doesn't bring any value and it is out of use at all. No one sends message to this channel: you send to the `listener.setRequestChannelName("myLogChannel");` directly though... Therefore a `WireTap` isn't performed at all as well.

I'm not sure how to help you since it isn't clear what you are going to use as a main channel and what should be used from the wire-tap.

**UPDATE**

So, you need to configure that `new WireTap("myLogChannel")` on this `toRouter` channel.

Comment: I want to use Channel Wiretap to log the message (and send the original message to the main channel)

Comment: OK! And what is your `main channel`? Were you able to implement at least a main flow? Let's consider logging later! your problem that you send to the `myLogChannel` from the JMS and your both services are listening exactly to this channel. That's very confusing...

Comment: I have edited my original post with the working main flow (without logging).
NOTE: We are using Spring Integration 4.3, so we can't use DSL

Comment: Do you want to wire-tap on the `toRouter` channel? We don't wire-tap on the code. Isn't it? And why didn't you show a working code in the beginning and asked a question how to proceed? What was the point to show broken code and expect reasonable answer? This is your code and it is really to hard for us to understand what you would like to achieve if you are confusing us. Sorry for such a rude tone, but that's hard to help someone who doesn't help himself even...

Comment: Yes, i want to wire tap on the toRouter channel. The first code was working for me  - i was not getting the proper behavior tho  - so that is why i asked the question.
The first and second examples are same for me, only the second includes other channel name and no logging.

I was following this example:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/28
(which i probably messed)

Comment: @Bean

    public MessageChannel toRouter(MessageChannel myLogChannel) {
        DirectChannel d = new DirectChannel();
        d.addInterceptor(new WireTap(myLogChannel));
        return d;
    }

Thanks a lot and sorry for the missunderstanding ! 
I couldn't get it to work with "ChannelName" as string,  It is working only with injected bean (as written in the comment)

Comment: Well, it is going to work with channel name when the `WireTap` is declared as a bean. In your case you inject it directly via code, not DI. Sorry for confusing on that side...